# In Oracle, how do I average two row values to create a new value?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g, average

I have the following data (under the Current sheet). I need to average the two pH values/rows on the same date to create a new row. How do I do this?

https://github.com/scottr2012/test_r_data/blob/master/PH_Test_Data.xlsx

I've tried:

```
CREATE TABLE data_2
AS
SELECT a.*, AVG(value) AS pH
FROM data_1 a
```

But I get a not a single group-group function error

Comment: Include sample results and data *in the question*.  No sane person is going to look at an Excel spreadsheet from an anonymous source.

Comment: How do I add data to the question? There is no clarification on this when posting the question.

Comment: @ScottR You can add data by [edit] ing the question and adding the DML statements to create and populate your source table (data_1), thereby turning your question into a [MCVE].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, you want to use analytic functions:

```
SELECT a.*, AVG(value) OVER (PARTITION BY date) AS pH
FROM data_1 a;
```

If you want aggregation, use `group by`:

```
select date, avg(value)
from data_1
group by date;
```

Comment: Just tried this and it calculates the average, but it still leaves the 2 rows that were used to calculate the average. I guess I could just pull the minimum (sorted by rowid) partitioned by date to get the single row?